# Invalid selector on 'querySelectorAll' using variable for the id

Tags: javascript

I have dynamic ID that has been passed through a variable. Unfortunately when try to reference it into the `querySelectorAll` I am getting an error:

```
Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document':'#paragraph-1 .is-available"' is not a valid selector.
```

My code is below

```
var x = ('"#' + dataID + ' is-available"');
var test = document.querySelectorAll (x);
console.log(test);
```

When I look into the console log it outputs it correctly to:

```
#paragraph-1 .is-available
```

Any idea as to how I should be referencing the variable into my `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: get rid of those `"` - i.e. `var x = ('#' + dataID + ' is-available');` because the string `#paragraph-1 .is-available` is valid, but the string `"#paragraph-1 .is-available"` is not (though, from the error you've shown, the code isn't exactly what you claim it is) - `var x = ('"#' + dataID + ' is-available"');` would result in something like `"#paragraph-1 is-available"` but the error is that `#paragraph-1 .is-available"` is invalid

Comment: And note that it needs to be `.is-available` and not just `is-available`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1. Get rid of the double quotes in your selector
2. Add replace the white space with a `.` in your selector for `is-available`.

You should get a proper result with this selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#' + dataID + '.is-available');
```

Update:

It is unclear whether you want to select all child elements of the element with the specified ID or all elements that have the specified ID and class. Keep the white space and add `.` to `is-available` if child elements are to be selected. Making your code as follows:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#' + dataID + ' .is-available');
```

Comment: look at the error ... look at the code ... see how the code could not possibly produce the error

Comment: Where in the post does it say that the `is-available` is *not* a child of the id?